# How to use adb shell controll android app?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an android demo.I want to use command in adb shell to make the demo do what I want.I may need an shell file.

The result I want like this.

```
root@device:/ # <shell> log "hello world"
```

then my app console "hello world" at logcat.

but I don't know how to connect them.

Comment: Don't know if your are looking to execute commads on the shell from the App but you can archive this with RootTools.

Comment: If you want to output "hello world" in logcat you can just use `Log` class, no need to execute commands in shell.

Comment: @axierjhtjz There's no need for rooting to execute commands in the shell.

Comment: @m0skit0 I know but it says root on the line he added so i thought that root was needed

Comment: I don't mean i want let android app execute the shell command, but i want let shell controll app.

Comment: Not only log, maybe I can let app do other things I'v defined in java code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send Intents to your app through the shell, although your app has to register the appropriate `BroadcastListener`. Here's a simple example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = MyActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String INTENT_FILTER = "com.example.myapp.TEST";
    public static final String EXTRA_KEY = "new_text";

    private class MyIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            final String newText = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_KEY);
            Log.d(TAG, "Received new text: " + newText);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        registerReceiver(new MyIntentReceiver(), new IntentFilter(INTENT_FILTER));
    }
}
```

Then you can do in shell:

```
am broadcast -a com.example.myapp.TEST -e "new_text" "New text"
```

And you will see how your app receives and logs it.

Comment: Thank you very much,it is what i want now. And also thanks others' help.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify: You want to send commands from adb shell (local android shell) to your app?
That's not possible without quite a few lines of code, and possible requires rooting of the device.

You'd be better of by just adding an UI to the app where you can call events.

Edit: As m0skit0 pointed out it is possible to send intents via commandline. This is definitely the cleanest solution.

Comment: I will read articles about tty. at first I think app to be a server, and the shell to be a client,but they are all in the local, so I think there may be any better idea?From your answer the tty device is an idea,but is there any other ways to connect shell and app?(Now i'm not actually know tty,so my question may be stupid).

Comment: I still recommend using the android UI to control your app. Why do you want to use the shell to control your app? Is it an app for a special purpose?

Comment: Not special purpose, I just think sometimes command in computer is easier

Comment: Wrong. You can send intents to your app from the shell, and does not require any rooting.

Comment: @m0skit0 you're right, totally forgot about that. Seems to be a much better and cleaner solution than some tty hacking!